# Parsing closed brackets in URL and http_build_query with it inserts number in closed bracket

Tags: php, parsing, urldecode

may not have explained this properly but here we go.

I have a URL that looks like http://www.test.co.uk/?page=2&area[]=thing&area[]=thing2

Multiple "area"s can be added or removed from the URL via links on the site. on each addition of n "area" I wanted to remove the "page" part of the URL. so it can be reset to page1. I used parse_url to take that bit out.

Then I built an http query so it could generate the URL properly without "page"

this resulted in "area%5B0%5D=" "area%5B1%5D=" instead of "area[]="

When I use urldecode, now it shows "area[0]=" and "area[1]="

I need it to be "[]" because when using a link to remove an area, it checks for the "[]=" - when it's [0] it doesn't recognise it. How do I keep it as "[]="?

See code below.

```
  $currentURL = currentURL();

    $parts = parse_url($currentURL);
   parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
   unset($query['page']);
   $currenturlfinal = http_build_query($query);
 urldecode($currenturlfinal);
  $currentURL = "?" . urldecode($currenturlfinal);
```

This is what I've done so far - it fixes the visual part in the URL - however I don't think I've solved anything as I've realised that what represents 'area' and 'thing' is not recognised as $key or $val as a result of what I think is parsing or reencoding the url in accordance with the code below. So I still can't remove 'areas' using the links

```
  $currentURL_with_QS2 = currentURL();

   $parts = parse_url($currentURL_with_QS2);
   parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
   unset($query['page']);
   $currenturlfinal = http_build_query($query);

   $currenturlfinal = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/simU', '[]', $currenturlfinal);
   urldecode($currenturlfinal);

   $currentURL_with_QS = "?" . $currenturlfinal;


   $numQueries = count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));

   $get = $_GET;



    if (activeCat($val)) { // if this category is already set

        $searchString = $key . '[]= ' . $val; // we build the query string to remove
```

I'm using Wordpress as well may I add - maybe there's a way to reset the pagination through Wordpress. of course even then - when I go to page 2 on any page it still changes the "[]" to "5b0%5d" etc....

EDIT: this is all part of a function that refers to $key (the area/category) and $val (name of area or category) which is echoed in the link itself

EDIT2: It works now!
I don't know why but I had to use the original code and make the adjustments I did before again and now it works exactly how I want it to! Yet I couldn't see any visible differences in both codes afterwards. Strange...

Comment: what about a regexp replacement to fix `http_build_query()`'s output ? or perhaps you might prefer to write an alternative to that function.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do this.
You could try with:

```
$currenturlfinal = http_build_query($query);
```

Where `$query` is querystring part w/o area parameters and then:

```
foreach ($areas as $area) {
    $currenturlfinal .= '&area[]='.$area;
}
```

UPD:
you could try with:

```
    $query = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/simU', '%5B%5D', $query);
```

just place it right after `http_build_query` call.

Comment: This won't work as I also have &category[]= - these are referenced in the script as $key (for area & category) and $val (one of a range of areas/categories eg "books")

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: See the edit - I'm not sure if parsing the URL is the right solution as it removes reference to the $key and $var which is essential to the function it appears...

Comment: Ahhh no it's okay, it's working now. I don't know why but I had to use the original code and make the adjustments I did before again and now it works exactly how I want it to! Strange...